# как из такого массива получить такой массив

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив

```html
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Первый',
    1 => NULL,
    2 => NULL,
    3 => NULL,
    4 => NULL,
    5 => NULL,
    6 => NULL,
    7 => NULL,
    8 => NULL,
    9 => NULL,
    10 => NULL,
    11 => NULL,
    12 => NULL,
    13 => NULL,
    14 => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Второй',
    1 => NULL,
    2 => NULL,
    3 => NULL,
    4 => NULL,
    5 => NULL,
    6 => NULL,
    7 => NULL,
    8 => NULL,
    9 => NULL,
    10 => NULL,
    11 => NULL,
    12 => NULL,
    13 => NULL,
    14 => NULL,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => '1476',
    1 => '96010',
    2 => 'инфо',
    3 => '2400',
    4 => '630.00',
    5 => '630.00',
    6 => '262.5',
    7 => 'данные ',
    8 => 'url',
    9 => 'числа',
    10 => '50',
    11 => '50',
    12 => NULL,
    13 => 'Name',
    14 => '4',
  ),
)
```

получить такой массив

```html
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Первый',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Первый',
      ),
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Первый'
      ),
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Первый',
      ),
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Второй',
      ),
      array (
        0 => '1476',
        1 => '96010',
        2 => 'инфо',
        3 => '2400',
        4 => '630.00',
        5 => '630.00',
        6 => '262.5',
        7 => 'данные ',
        8 => 'url',
        9 => 'числа',
        10 => '50',
        11 => '50',
        12 => NULL,
        13 => 'Name',
        14 => '4',
        15 => 'Второй',
      )
```

делаю все на php никак не пойму как сделать

Comment: Я вон вам ответ написал, а потом вздрогнул, перечитав вопрос, я не понял, а что именно вы хотите? У вас и так массив массив, или вы хотите чтобы каждый массив получил свою переменную, и к нему можно было обращаться через свою переменную?

Comment: там неизвестно сколько будет массивов

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов к сожалению не один из вариантов мне не подошёл

Comment: Поясните что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы все ваши массивы в главном массиве(а их может быть больше) получали свои переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример.

```
$arr = [
    0 =>
        [
            0 => 'Первый',
            1 => NULL,
            2 => NULL,
            3 => NULL,
            4 => NULL,
            5 => NULL,
            6 => NULL,
            7 => NULL,
            8 => NULL,
            9 => NULL,
            10 => NULL,
            11 => NULL,
            12 => NULL,
            13 => NULL,
            14 => NULL,
        ],
    1 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ],
    2 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ],
    3 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ],
    4 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ],
    5 =>
        [
            0 => 'Второй',
            1 => NULL,
            2 => NULL,
            3 => NULL,
            4 => NULL,
            5 => NULL,
            6 => NULL,
            7 => NULL,
            8 => NULL,
            9 => NULL,
            10 => NULL,
            11 => NULL,
            12 => NULL,
            13 => NULL,
            14 => NULL,
        ],
    6 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ],
    7 =>
        [
            0 => '1476',
            1 => '96010',
            2 => 'инфо',
            3 => '2400',
            4 => '630.00',
            5 => '630.00',
            6 => '262.5',
            7 => 'данные ',
            8 => 'url',
            9 => 'числа',
            10 => '50',
            11 => '50',
            12 => NULL,
            13 => 'Name',
            14 => '4',
        ]
];


$newArr = [];

foreach($arr as $value) {
    $newArr[] = $value;
}

print_r($newArr);
```

На выходе получим тот результат что вам нужно. Можно применить еще более короткий и практичный способ.

```
$newArr = array_map(function ($elem){
    return $elem;
}, $arr);
```

На выходе также будет нужный результат.

Ну и на крайняк после последнего уточнения, чтобы каждый массив лег в сво переменную.

```
$newArr = array_map(function ($elem){
    return $elem;
}, $arr);

list($arr, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, $arr5, $arr6) = $arrTwo;
```